# No known instance method for selector 'receivedItemsJSON'

Tags: ios, objective-c, api, delegates

I'm trying to build a test iOS app to parse JSON from eBay's API and I'm having trouble relaying the response over to the delegate. I'm receiving the warning `No known instance method for selector` errors for both my `fetchingItemsFailedWithError` and `receivedItemsJSON` methods in my ItemCommunicator implementation.

XYZItemCommunicator.m:

```
#import "XYZItemCommunicator.h"
#import "XYZItemCommunicatorDelegate.h"
@implementation XYZItemCommunicator

- (void)searchItems
{
    NSString *urlAsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1?SECURITY-APPNAME=**************&OPERATION-NAME=findItemsByKeywords&SERVICE-VERSION=1.12.0&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=JSON&callback=_cb_findItemsByKeywords&REST-PAYLOAD&sortOrder=PricePlusShippingLowest&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=7&outputSelector=AspectHistogram&itemFilter(0).name=Condition&itemFilter(0).value(0)=New&itemFilter(1).name=MaxPrice&itemFilter(1).value=450.00&itemFilter(1).paramName=Currency&itemFilter(1).paramValue=USD&itemFilter(2).name=MinPrice&itemFilter(2).value=350.00&itemFilter(2).paramName=Currency&itemFilter(2).paramValue=USD&itemFilter(3).name=ListingType&itemFilter(3).value=FixedPrice&keywords=Moto+x+16gb+unlocked"];
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlAsString];
    NSLog(@"%@", urlAsString);

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url] queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

        if (error) {
            [self.delegate fetchingItemsFailedWithError:error];
        } else {
            [self.delegate receivedItemsJSON:data];
        }
    }];
}

@end
```

XYZItemCommunicator.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol ItemCommunicatorDelegate;

@interface XYZItemCommunicator : NSObject
@property (weak, nonatomic) id<ItemCommunicatorDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

XYZItemCommunicatorDelegate.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol XYZItemCommunicatorDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)receivedItemsJSON:(NSData *)objectNotation;
- (void)fetchingItemsFailedWithError:(NSError *)error;
@end
```

Comment: What object (view controller) have you set as your delegate for this view controller?  Whatever object you set as the delegate for this view controller must implement the two protocol methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your protocol name. you start with

> ItemCommunicatorDelegate

and change to

> XYZItemCommunicatorDelegate